# Android Studio external Project Import with Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have an external project that I would like to import into my Android project and the project does not have a gradle file. The android classes can not find the external project classes even when putting a blank gradle file in the external project. The current directory structure is as follow:

root
- {build.gradle & settings.gradle}
- app
- - {build.gradle}
- - src
- - - main
- - - - {android files here}
- - libraries
- - - ExternalProject
- - - - {no gradle file exists}
- - - - src
- - - - - com
- - - - - - domain
- - - - - - - projectname
- - - - - - - - {java files here}

For the 'root' settings gradle file:

```
include ':app', ':app:libraries:ExternalProject'
```

For the 'app' gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile project(':app:libraries:ExternalProject')
}
```

Comment: If you import non-gradle projects to Android Studio, it automatically converts them to gradle projects.

Comment: This was more of a drag-n-drop operation. I created the 'libraries' folder, then dragged the project in there. When I was trying to do an import, Android Studio kept informing me to specify location of the gradle or android eclipse project and would not let me import the project as a module to the android project.

Comment: Okay.So it works now?

Comment: No, only thing i've done to get the gradle to build is add a gradle file to the ExternalProject directory with the following line "apply plugin: 'java'" ... but when working in any of the android classes, it does not find the any of the classes in the external project.